# 'Response is Constant' error in R - GLMER

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, linear-model

I have some categorical data which is coded 0/1 at the observation (in this case, interest area) level. I have averaged these values per trial, which provides me with a probability value between 0 and 1.

I am running GLME's in R using `family = Gamma(link = identity)` (continuous) and `family = binomial(link = logit)` within the models, however for the averaged categorical data I am struggling.

Some averages have a value of 0, meaning I cannot use gamma family/identity link; whereas since we have more than 2 unique values, I don't believe I can use the binomial family/logit link.

I am aware I *could* run LME's without specifying the family/link (since all of the averaged variables are perfect normal distributions), however I am tied to running GLME's due to pre-registration processes linked with the analysis.

Here's an example of a sample of the data, and the code, that I am using

```
datafile <- structure(list(
  depvar= c(0.00000000,0.02197802,0.37948718,0.00000000,0.15789474,  0.00000000,0.00000000,0.18181818,0.07142857,0.00000000,0.06060606,0.94366197), 
  window = c("window", "window", "window", "nowindow", "nowindow", "nowindow", "window", "window", "window", "nowindow", "nowindow", "nowindow"),
  trial_sound = c("quiet", "standard", "deviant", "quiet", "standard", "deviant", "quiet", "standard", "deviant", "quiet", "standard", "deviant"),
item = c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
pp = c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
  .Names = c("depvar","window", "trial_sound", "item", "pp"),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

```
depvar.glmer1 = glmer(depvar ~ window*trial_sound + (1+ window*trial_sound|pp) + 
(1+ window*trial_sound|item),control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000)),
 data = datafile, family= Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

I posted the question on Stack Overflow believing it was an error in the code I used, however I was directed here to request further help. Once suggestion on Stack Overflow was to use the number of observations (e.g. nIA) within the group (i.e. in this case, the number of interest areas in a trial) and then use `weights = nIA` within the model. However, I again received the error  'response is constant'.

Any advice and references/resources that may help me would be very much appreciated!